# How to catch the intent used for starting an app?

Tags: android

I am trying to collect the starting time of different apps, that is the time when the user tab some app's icon.

I guess there may be an intent was sent to respond this event, if so, how to catch this intent, so I would know an app was just starting, and record the current time?

Comment: I doubt you can really do that. Security and so on..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I guess there may be an intent was sent to respond this event

No, sorry. `startActivity()` only uses an `Intent` with the starting activity (and perhaps a chooser). There is no broadcast `Intent` regarding the start of an activity.

> I am trying to collect the starting time of different apps, that is the time when the user tab some app's icon.

That is not really possible.

A classic workaround for this was to keep tabs on LogCat. This technique has been blocked as of Android 4.2.

Beyond that, you are welcome to try polling `ActivityManager` or some script-kiddie solution like that, if you don't mind blowing a lot of battery and don't need good accuracy.